# Trying to install a vimball having vimballPlugin installed

Tags: vim

I want to install this [plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/download_script.php?src_id=16854), so first I extract the content of the zip and then I do:

```
$ vim camelcasemotion.vba
```

Then I do:

```
:so %
```

but I get this error:

> Error detected while processing /tmp/camelcasemotion.vba: line    2:
>   E492: Not an editor command: UseVimball Press ENTER or type command to
>   continue

[Here](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1905) you have the page of the plugin.
I have vim 7.3 and vimballPlugin installed as you can see here:

```
:/usr/share/vim/vim73/plugin$ ls
getscriptPlugin.vim  gzip.vim  matchparen.vim  netrwPlugin.vim  README.txt  rrhelper.vim  spellfile.vim  tarPlugin.vim  tohtml.vim  vimballPlugin.vim  zipPlugin.vi
```

Comment: Are you sure that the plugin is also active? Try `:verbose command UseVimball` to verify.

Comment: @IngoKarkat, i tried what you said and I get this "No user-defined commands found".

Comment: @tirengarfio Are you sure you don’t have `set noloadplugins`/`set nolpl` somewhere in the vimrc? Do you edit runtimepath here (search for something like `set rtp`/`set runtimepath`/`&rtp`/`&runtimepath`)? What does `type vim` in the shell show? Same for `echo $VIMRUNTIME` (in shell. In vim also makes sense to check). What do `verbose autocmd SourceCmd` and `verbose autocmd SourcePre` report in vim?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I feel you pain, and am - was - just going through the same issues.

What I did incorrectly was:

- I put `so /usr/share/vim/[some dirs]/vimballPlugin.vim"` in my vimrc

I then did `: scriptnames` and saw that the plugin hadn't loaded, well, it wasn't on the list.

What I then did correctly was:

- I actually sourced the plugin myself from within vim: `so /usr/share/vim/[some dirs]/vimballPlugin.vim` and it had loaded:

`: scriptnames` then gave

```
       :
       :
   22: ~/.vim/plugin_loadManually/Align.vba
   23: /usr/share/vim/vim73/plugin-manual/vimballPlugin.vim
   24: /usr/share/vim/vim73/autoload/vimball.vim
```

The "Align" plugin, that I had been failing to install (from a vimball) I have now also installed (via the `so %` command on the vimball, as per normal.

Comment: Found this useful with Neovim on Windows and installing unicode.vim

Answer (score 3):

Be sure that you have a .vimrc in your path for VIM to open, with at least the following (as found here: http://www.mail-archive.com/vim@vim.org/msg12581.html).  This solved it for me.

```
" =====================================================================
"  Initialize: {{{1
set nocp
if version >= 600
  filetype plugin indent on
endif
```

Answer (score 1):

> No user-defined commands found

That explains the error; the Vimball plugin isn't installed (though you found it somewhere in your file system) or has been explicitly turned off (there's a `:let g:loaded_vimballPlugin = 1` somewhere). The reason depends on your environment, how / who installed Vim. The `:scriptnames` command shows you what is active, and :set runtimepath? shows the directories. Or maybe just pragmatically download the Vimball plugin from vim.org and install it again?!

Comment: It is installed: the location of the file shows it perfectly. But it is not loaded. There are plenty of reasons why it might be so (I have listed how to check for most of them in the comment to the question), but plugin being *not installed* is *not* on the list here.

Comment: @ZyX: Thanks for the note; I consider "not loaded" as not properly installed, too. Instead of getting lost on details, I extended the answer a bit.

Comment: Installed usually means “placed in a proper location” (normally “… with appropriate initialization scripts run” (like updating font cache, registering MIME types and so on) but vimball requires none and neither it is required by the meaning of the word). I have never seen “installed” used as a synonym to “loaded”. Oxford dictionary completely agrees in this case: “place or fix (equipment or machinery) in position ready for use”, not a single word about requirement to actually use it, or not to prevent it from being used.