# vimballPlugin.vim is loaded but cannot install from vimball

Tags: vim, plugins

I tried to install a plugin `netrw.vba` using vimball on vim 7.3 with `:source %`, but got this error

```
line    2:
E492: Not an editor command: UseVimball
```

I came across this post [Trying to install a vimball having vimballPlugin installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10399186/trying-to-install-a-vimball-having-vimballplugin-installed), and followed the steps mentioned there to try fixing it, but did not work. `:scriptnames` shows `{...}/gvim73/share/vim/vim73/plugin/vimballPlugin.vim` so it seems to be loaded correctly.

What else could I explore to figure out this issue? Is there some setting I missed here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case the `plugin/vimballPlugin.vim` script has been loaded, the only conditions that prevent the definition of the command are:

1. you have `:set compatible`, falling back to old vi behavior (usually not what you want)
2. you have defined `g:loaded_vimballPlugin` somewhere, explicitly suppressing the plugin
3. something does `:delcommand UseVimball` after the plugin is sourced

Find out which applies to you, and fix it.