# E492 during clang_complete installation for vim

Tags: ubuntu, vim, clang-complete

I tried to install clang_complete for vim.
I have downloaded source and when I try to make it, it gives me this:

```
E492: Not an editor command %MkVimball! clang_complete.vmb
```

any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the *Vimball* plugin (which defines the `:MkVimball` command) isn't active or installed. That's strange; it ships with Vim. Please investigate what's wrong with your setup (`:set rtp?` and `:scriptnames` will help), or re-install the plugin, e.g. from [vim.org](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1502).

Or just install the clang_complete from a different format, e.g. the downloadable ZIPs from the [vim-scripts.org mirror](https://github.com/vim-scripts/clang-complete).

Comment: The problem was that MKvimball script was missing. I made a sample .vimrc cause I had not anyone thanks to [Alex](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15840298/1805756) and then downloaded mkvimball.vba, opened it using vim and ran :so %.